# Viewing table data in SQLite Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

Quick, simple way to view data inside table in SQLite database in Ruby on Rails using terminal or any other way that's easy, quick and simple.

Answer (score 2):

`rails c` and then:

```
ModelClass.all
like Post.all
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 2, open the console in terminal by using the command

**ruby script/console**

And for new rails version use the command

**rails c**

After that you can get the data from table by using command

**ModelName.all**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`rails console` or `rails c` and then:

```
> @list = ModelName.all
```

For example:

```
> @employees = Employee.all
```